# Horizontal list of images from ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, windows-10-universal

I like to show images from ObservableCollection in horizontal scroll list like in Windows Store but i would scroll it horizontaly like in FlipView with all images being visible. I have something like that at this moment:

```
<FlipView x:Name="MasterListView" ItemsSource="{x:Bind PopularTVSeries}" 
            Grid.Row="1" Margin="10,10,10,0" Height="278">
    <FlipView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:PopularTVSeries">
            <Image Source="{x:Bind poster_path}" Width="185" Height="278"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </FlipView.ItemTemplate>
</FlipView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are controls to do it.

#### Method 1:

Using [Carousel XAML Control](http://www.uwpcommunitytoolkit.com/en/master/controls/Carousel/) by UWPCommunityToolkit. Install [Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/) nuget package to use it.

Here is the syntax

```
<controls:Carousel x:Name="CarouselControl" InvertPositive="0"
                    ItemDepth="0" ItemMargin="0"
                    ItemRotationX="0" ItemRotationY="0"
                    ItemRotationZ="0" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Carousel>
```

For more info download [UWP Community Toolkit Sample App](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/p/uwp-community-toolkit-sample-app/9nblggh4tlcq)

#### Method 2:

Using [Carousel Control](https://github.com/wasteam/waslibs#carousel) by AppStudio. Install [WindowsAppStudio.Uwp](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAppStudio.Uwp) nuget package to use it.

Here is the syntax

```
<controls:Carousel MaxItems="5" MinHeight="240" 
                   MaxHeight="480" GradientOpacity="0.3">
    <controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
</controls:Carousel>
```

For more info download [Windows App Studio Sample App](http://www.microsoft.com/en-in/store/p/windows-app-studio-sample-app/9wzdncrfj3pj)

#### Method 3:

Using `GridView`

```
<GridView ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollMode="Enabled">
    <GridView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Image/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemTemplate>
    <GridView.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </GridView.ItemsPanel>
</GridView>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. Maybe connection with ObservableCollecion is the problem

Comment: @K.Kempski Which one did you tried? Can you attach your code in the question?

Comment: x:Bind* sorry Vijay

Comment: @K.Kempski You didn't set `ItemsSource` for Carousel

Comment: I bind source like in question example code and it didn't work

Comment: Never mind. It works! I will mark you're answer as Correnct. Thank you very much!

Comment: Can i make items clickable?

Comment: @K.Kempski What do you mean by "clickable"?

Comment: I would like to click on item and in click event gets it id, name etc

Comment: @K.Kempski Use `SelectionChanged` event

Comment: Then i can't scroll images, immadietly it is selected

Comment: @K.Kempski I didn't understand. "Then I can't scroll images" - You can scroll

Comment: https://puu.sh/wXcel/a7f93a2c45.png i would scroll horizontaly and be able to handle click on image

Comment: I would like to have different event in mouse click

Comment: You can retemplate it. (OR) I think it is possible with the method 2

Answer (score 0):

Final working code:

```
<controls:Carousel 
            ItemsSource="{x:Bind popularTVSeries}"
            x:Name="MasterListView"
            InvertPositive="True"
            ItemDepth="153"
            ItemMargin="0"
            ItemRotationX="0"
            ItemRotationY="29"
            ItemRotationZ ="0"
            Orientation="Horizontal"
            SelectedIndex="3"
            Grid.Row="1">

            <controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>
                <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseOut"/>
            </controls:Carousel.EasingFunction>

            <controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="data:PopularTVSeries">
                    <Image
                        Width="185"
                        Height="278"
                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                        Source="{x:Bind poster_path}"
                        Stretch="Uniform" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:Carousel.ItemTemplate>

        </controls:Carousel>
```